# Pie-chart in ASP.NET C# using data from Firebase

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase, pie-chart

I want to create a pie chart to visualise some data from Firebase using ASP.NET and C# . I have no idea how to start. Can you please help me with some code ? Thank you !

Comment: Please mention your current code which you are using and the issue which you are facing when running the code.

Comment: Google charts is a good place to look. You can use their javascript library to plot lots of types of chart. https://developers.google.com/chart. The pie charts are here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart